# Difference between dot product, inner product, cross product, outer product. And what are their symbols?

Tags: cross-product, outer-product

When I was learning machine learning, I often encounter these terms, yet I don't the difference and relationship between them. And what are the symbols for them? Can someone help me?

Comment: I'd be interested to know why cross products were discussed in machine learning. Can you link me to that?

Comment: sorry, I didn't make it clear: I was just curious about the difference between these terms and this curiosity initially started during my learning of ML. I haven't seen the use of cross-product in ML.

Answer (score 2):

The [*inner product*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition) is denoted $\langle x,\,y\rangle$ (or occasionally $(x,\,y)$) or $\langle x|y\rangle$. It mustn't be cofused with an [*outer product*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product#Definition), which is basically a square matrix. You may see it denoted as $\sum_{ij}|i\rangle\langle j|$.

For your purposes, all these products will be on a finite-dimensional vector space, and with respect to some orthonormal basis the inner product will just be a [*dot product*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Algebraic_definition) $x\cdot y=\sum_ix_i^\ast y_i$ (you only need the ${}^\ast$ if the space is complex). In a space of uncountable dimension, the $\sum$ in the dot (outer) product becomes a single (double) integral.

The [*cross product*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Coordinate_notation) $x\times y$ almost certainly refers to something exclusive to $3$ dimensions, [but](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seven-dimensional_cross_product) [sometimes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Generalizations) it's something related but different.